# Dynamic data storage with search and mapping for java project

Tags: java, database, nosql

I'm looking for good dynamic data storage mainly based on JAVA, or to have ability to be really easy used by JAVA.

Main problem in my project is in fast that our data structures will not remain stable, even more structures will be changed from time to time, so basically casual Relation Data Base will lost fight on that level, because drop and add new columns are pretty risky. Which means that some NOSQL or XML based or even file based storage will be usable there.

All inputs are coming from other resource which could be a SOAP callback, JASON call back, import from CSV file or manual input, based on that have to create entities and than to fill it with data.

Last thing on which I have to keep eye on is to bring unstructured, semi-structured and differently structured data in a unified form. Beside of this would be nice to have ability of maintenance of huge amount of data in accepted time duration.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are RDBMs a lost fight on that level? What is risky about drop and add new column? How about in-memory RDBMS such as oracle timesten or hypersonic sql?

Comment: Do you need to perform an expressive query on this unified form? I assume for each type of input, you are going to normalize it into the unified form?

Comment: @Ashkan Aryan  we can use only open source technologies, Oracle is a great DB, but I can't use it on this project :(

Comment: @momo yes I'm going to normalize it and than to perform queries, but for each let say diff input set I have to create a usable db table, or entity or file or what ever and than to perform search on it...of course I can use Lucine/Solr or something similar for indexing that is not a big deal.

Comment: @vaske Have you tried MongoDB? I think what you are saying, you have the unified form, but you don't know if that's the final structure and thus you want the ability to dynamically change the structure on the fly without the hassle of SQL structure changes. I am just suggesting MongoDB because it has worked for me in the past for similar purpose.

Comment: @momo well I'm looking for best solution MongoDB is one of them so basically I'll get all structure in some sorta XML format than will populate an db (let say MongoDB), but that XML configuration is not stable, I mean it is gonig to be changed from time to time. Just read about MongoDB problem with structure changes, did you have something like that? Or am I free to go with it?

Comment: I think you are looking for an extensible database, its easy if you have already tables for the number of entities. Search for extensible database schema.  btw I am working on a general solution for this totally dynamic (no constant entity tables) and extensible database with self-referencing the same type of records or (combinations of possible forms of an entity properties). I will post the answer if I get success. :)

Answer (score 1):

[HyperSQL](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html) is open source and free.

Comment: Looks nice I had doubt about MongoDB and CouchDB, looks like HYperSQL is something similar..thanks